# Test if there are values shared in multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

How can I test whether there are values shared in multiple columns of a pandas DataFrame? For example, this is OK:

```
      A    B    C
0   aaa  fff  lll
1   bbb  ggg  mmm
2   ccc  hhh  nnn
3   ddd  iii  ooo
4   eee  jjj  ppp
```

but this is not

```
      A    B    C
0   aaa  fff  lll
1   bbb  ggg  mmm
2   ccc  hhh  nnn
3   ddd  iii  bbb
4   eee  jjj  ppp
```

because `bbb` exists in multiple columns (A and C).

Comment: Are all your columns of the same obj data type?  And are you expecting something like a boolean array that corresponds to each unique value with some sort of "True/False this value is represented in 2+ columns" indication?

Comment: Yeah, consistent datatypes (integers). Just used strings here to make it easier to look at. I don't need a fancy boolean map of offending cells, but I would like to get out which values are offenders, and which columns they exist in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get intersection between all combination of columns first, convert to `numpy array`, then to `boolean` and test at least one `True`:

```
from itertools import combinations
a = [set(df[i[0]]) & set(df[i[1]]) for i in combinations(df.columns,2)]
b = np.array(a).astype(bool).any()
```

For first df:

```
print (a)
[set(), set(), set()]

print (b)
False
```

For second df:

```
print (a)
[set(), {'bbb'}, set()]

print (b)
True
```

For more information is possible use (untested):

```
d = {i:set(df[i[0]]) & set(df[i[1]]) for i in combinations(df.columns,2)}

s = pd.Series(d)

s = s[s.astype(bool)]
```